# protocol-buffers parse result Incorrect using ByteString?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

i want to save protocol-buffers object via string, in JAVA
but when i use ByteString with encode UTF_8 ,parse result not correct

```
public static void test2() throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {

    CrcCertInfoRequest data = CrcCertInfoRequest.newBuilder().setCompanyType(222).build();
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    String proStr = data.toByteString().toString(charset);
    ByteString bs2 = ByteString.copyFrom(proStr, charset);

    String json = ObjectMapperUtils.toJSON(data);
    System.out.println("proStr=" + proStr.length() + "json=" + json.length());

    System.out.println(ObjectMapperUtils.toJSON(CrcCertInfoRequest.parseFrom(bs2)));
    System.out.println(ObjectMapperUtils.toJSON(ObjectMapperUtils.fromJSON(json, CrcCertInfoRequest.class)));
}
```

code output:

```
proStr=3json=119
{"appId":0,"createSource":0,"certType":0,"accountType":0,"companyType":3104751,"industryCategory1":0,"industryCategory2":0}
{"appId":0,"createSource":0,"certType":0,"accountType":0,"companyType":222,"industryCategory1":0,"industryCategory2":0}
```

the integer field companyType parse result is incorrect.supposed to be 222 but is 3104751

i tried other charset ,use ISO_8859_1  is ok ,but i'm not sure it's always ok.

protobuf version is protobuf-java-3.16.1.jar
java version is jdk1.8.0_171.jdk

how can i save and parse protobuf data using string in java?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: in my case ,i have to use an api only accept string params ,so i try to convert protobuf to string to transport data

Comment: I'd consider Base64 encoding the data.

Answer (score 1):

ByteString is an immutable sequence of bytes and is not an actual String. Interpreting the bytes as UTF-8 does not work because it's not UTF-8 data. It's also not ISO_8859_1 or any other String encoding even if the parsing is lenient enough to not throw an error.

> how can I save and parse protobuf data using string in java?

Convert the raw bytes to Base64.